# Flask-OAuthlib to implement OAuth implicit flow

Tags: flask, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider, flask-oauthlib

Is it feasible to implement oauth provider implicit flow using Flask-OAuthlib?

I have been trying this for more than a week now. I can't share codes because of some internal company policy.

My issue is OAuthlib has everything predefined: from what arguments to pass to the type of arguments. And, most of these are not even needed in the implicit flow. If I try to work around these, it starts throwing multiple errors. As long as I have `OAuthlib decorators` on, I'm not allowed to bypass these API internals. And somehow I feel the Flask-OAuthlib is skewed towards authorization flow.

Please, provide your point of view. Because I'm definitely missing something. Or has anyone tried implementing it earlier, and is it achievable?

Comment: resolved! It turned out I was doing something entirely different which wasn't even required. I had some how stuck to RFC definition/suggestion and was trying to get flow triggered from client, and was building that client using Flask-OAuthlib, which was just plain wrong. So now my OAuth provider is up and running.